# Flutter: display text from HTTP response

Tags: flutter

I have a link.txt file that i want to display it's content on a text widget

I tried this approach

```
try {
  HttpClient client = HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse(arbitaryLink.txt)).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response
        .transform(Utf8Decoder())
        .listen((contents) {
          // Do something here with contents
          return Text(contents);
    });
  });
} catch (exception) {
  print(exception);
}
```

contents is the response text .. whenever i try using it outside of it's scope, i get null value.
i tried returning Text, i even tried assigning it to a static variable but i got nothing.

Soo.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: outside of its scope? what do you mean by that? also, what is null then? `HttpClientResponse response`?

Comment: It means outside of this
.listen((contents) {
          // Do something here with contents
          return Text(contents);
    }

Comment: i dont understand you, how do you expect to use `contents` variable outside `listen`? what do you want to achieve actually? are you aware of `StreamBuilder`?

Comment: I don't.
i may rephrase is,
 i can't assign the content value to any other parameter, 
if i write a function and gave it the contents value, it will be null

Comment: so what do you want to achieve? what "other parameter" do you mean?

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, Can u provide me with a full working exampe?

Comment: yes, see `StreamBuilder` documentation

Comment: I want to display the content of a text file link on a Text widget ,

Comment: `"I want to display the content of a text file link on a Text widget"` - you should have said that from the beginning - see `StreamBuilder` documentation then - it has some example on how to use it

Comment: I did say it :D, i will .. thanks :))

Comment: ok i missed that - your "outside of scope" confused me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i solved

```
Future<String> _fetchBtaqa() async {
final response = await http.get('https://www.albetaqa.site/social/data/alwaraqa/02quran/1quran03/p-quran116.txt');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var decoded = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
  print(decoded);

  return decoded;
} else {
  return "Error";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If by outside its scope you mean that you are returning the value of the response and then trying to use it in some widget, then the case might be that you are not waiting for the client to fetch the response.

1) make sure the when you print contents in the scope you are getting a value

2) put the api call or the networking call in a function and add the await keyword to wait for the response.

3) When the response succeeds you can call setState to rebuild the widget with the new value of contents

Comment: I did make sure of it, it gets printed but doesn't show on the mobile screen 

can u provide a full example?